# .map() return array of undefined values on Array(x)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I `console.log(Array(2))` I am able to find `map` prototype function. But when I use it, this returns an array of undefined.

```js
let result = Array(2).map((o, i) => {
  return i;
});

console.log(result);
```

I know I can use `fill()` or spread operator on `Array(2)` before using the `map()` but I'm just wondering why I'm getting this behavior.

Comment: Many (most) Array methods do not act on elements that have never been set to any value, which is true of all elements of an array newly-constructed with the Array constructor.

Comment: Note that, contrary to what the snippet console says, you're not actually getting `[undefined, undefined]` - rather, you're getting a (nearly) *empty object* with a `.length` of 2

Comment: Use `Array.from({ length: 2 }, (_, i) => i)` instead.